# How do you link an image to another page?

Tags: html, css

I have a div, and within it is an image that should work as a link to another page. There is some text laid over it. located here https://wearehomefolks.com/index.php/home/

I have taken this from somewhere else on the web, I may have modified it a little.

I just want the image to link out to the other internal pages. And keep the hover effect.

When I hover over the images of which there are 5, there is no linking action. What is going wrong here please?

```
<div class="hvrbox">
   <a href="https://wearehomefolks.com/index.php/product-category/home-collection/">
    <img src="https://wearehomefolks.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Homefolks_Instruments_brass_edition_homefolks_homepage.jpg" alt="Mountains" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom">
   </a>
    <div class="hvrbox-layer_top">
        <div class="hvrbox-text">HOME COLLECTION
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.hvrbox,
.hvrbox * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hvrbox {
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.hvrbox img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_bottom {
    display: block;
      width: 100%;

}
.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_top {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: #fff;
    /*padding: 15px;*/
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_top,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_top {
    opacity: 1;
}
.hvrbox .hvrbox-text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    line-height:4.5rem;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hvrbox .hvrbox-text_mobile {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179); /* for old browsers */
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.7);
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    display: none;
}
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-text_mobile {
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You're clicking on `<div class="hvrbox-layer_top">` which is on top of the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `pointer-events: none` to the overlay (i.e. the CSS rule for `.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_top`). That way the click can "go through it" to the linked image to trigger the link:

```css
.hvrbox,
.hvrbox * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hvrbox {
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.hvrbox img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_bottom {
    display: block;
      width: 100%;

}
.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_top {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: #fff;
    /*padding: 15px;*/
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    pointer-events:none;
}
.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_top,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_top {
    opacity: 1;
}
.hvrbox .hvrbox-text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    line-height:4.5rem;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hvrbox .hvrbox-text_mobile {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179); /* for old browsers */
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.7);
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    display: none;
}
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-text_mobile {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hvrbox">
   <a href="https://wearehomefolks.com/index.php/product-category/home-collection/">
    <img src="https://wearehomefolks.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Homefolks_Instruments_brass_edition_homefolks_homepage.jpg" alt="Mountains" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom">
   </a>
    <div class="hvrbox-layer_top">
        <div class="hvrbox-text">HOME COLLECTION
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```